# C# send email with Outlook - No attachment in Outbox

Tags: c#, email, outlook, attachment

I have a program that is using Outlook to send messages with attachments. It is working ok, sending emails with attachments but in outbox there is no attachment in the message. When somebody receive the message the attachment is visible but in outbox not.
Here is some code:

```
        Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
        mail.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatPlain;
        int iAttachType = (int)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue;  
        mail.Attachments.Add(Application.StartupPath+"/"+attachment, iAttachType, null, attachment);
        mail.To = email;
        mail.Subject = "Something";
        mail.Body = "Some body";
        mail.Send();
```

Before this I use:

```
    private Outlook.Application outlookApp;
    private Outlook._NameSpace outlookNameSpace;
    private Outlook.MAPIFolder outbox;
```

and

```
            outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
            outlookNameSpace = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            outlookNameSpace.Logon(null, null, false, false);
            outbox = outlookNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderOutbox);
```

My outlook program is connected with Microsoft Exchange Serwer. When I was using an application written in C++ it saved attachment in messages in outbox.

Thx for help!

Answer (score 0):

You could be working with an old version of the outlook item.

This can happen if you keep references to your mail items, rec-patterns, inspectors and some other types [that I now forgot] longer than you need them.

Your reference will often point to the old version of the item and keeping it can also prevent you from getting a reference to the updated one (the one with the attachment), even when events (Folder.BeforeItemMove) are triggered.

Also, have you tried if mail.Save() would do anything for you?

This is what I use as soon as I am done with an item.

```
public static void NullAndRelease(object o)
{
    if (o == null) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        int releaseResult = 0;
        do {
            releaseResult = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(o);
        } while (releaseResult >= 0);
    } catch {
    } finally {
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    }
}
```

The catch has no message and is not important in my case. It is there if someone would pass in a reference that leads to something other than a com object. You can also try FinalReleaseComObject(o).

Comment: You could also make it a bool, but in my case it is not needed.

Comment: When I use save I get:Ten element został przeniesiony lub usunięty. (This element was moved or deleted)

Comment: What's more. When I log in into Web interface of my mail, in the outbox there are messages with attachments.... I still don't get your solution ;/

Comment: Check [this post](http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2008/10/30/releasing-office-objects-net/), more specifically "Q: What are the consequences of not releasing some COM object?...". [This](http://www.add-in-express.com/forum/read.php?FID=5&TID=4107) also states that you need to release the returning COM object after accessing the Attachments property.

Comment: Ok so I should try to call this function with my outlook parameter after sending email?

Comment: You should call NullAndRelease as soon as you are done with a reference.    I.E: if you do var attachment = outlookItem.Attachments[0] in the beginning of a method, call NullAndRelease(attachment) after you are done (in no need of the reference) with it.    You should release it latest at the end of the method. You also can't keep any references (to inspectors, items, attachments etc etc. Read the above post) on a class level if you are not very very aware of how your class will be used/misused.    To answer your question, if you're done with the attachment after you send the mail, release it.